# Additive space in the lower part with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Using the tcolorbox package to produce exercises for a textbook, I use the option invisible to let space for students for writing their solutions. In practice, the students need more space to write the solution than take the solution written. So how can I add a vertical space, say 20mm, for the option `invisible`? More, how can I play on this space, so add 10mm in the `invisible` part for short exercises, and 20mm for long ones ?

I give the program used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    segmentation style={double=white,draw=green!20!black,double distance=1pt,solid},
    lowerbox=invisible,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\[f^\prime(x) = \cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.\]
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to add the `invisible` option where you used to place it. (And may be comment it out)

Comment: @koleygr This option is made with the command `lowerbox=invisible,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about this answer, but you can always fix a certain `height` for the whole box or `add to natural height` some space. This space is divided between top and lower parts but you decide how. If all should go to lower part, use `space to lower` option. More information in section [4.10 Height control](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=53).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    segmentation style={double=white,draw=green!20!black,double distance=1pt,solid},
    lowerbox=invisible,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\[f^\prime(x) = \cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.\]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}{Ex2}[coltitle=cyan!80!black, add to natural height=2cm, space to lower]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\[f^\prime(x) = \cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.\]
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to comment your solution one year after. This solution will be very useful for me if I can "automate" the command  `add to natural height=2cm`, so to transform it to `add to natural height=xx cm`, where `xx` is a variable, I can choose. Any Idea ?

Comment: It was very simple to "automate" it ... It suffices to add a variable, as `{m+O{}+m}`, then to add a command `add to natural height=#3cm, space to lower,` so then choose a value for #3 instead of 2 to obtain #3 cm. Have you a more beautiful idea ? Thank you

Comment: This is the idea I was going to propose. Good job.

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Just a comment from `tcolorbox` documentation about `add to natural height` (page 53): "The height control keys are only applicable to unbreakable boxes. If a box is set to be /tcb/breakable, the height is always computed according to the natural height." So it seems that you can not modify lower part height in breakable boxes without undesired effects.

Comment: Yes I saw this on my breakable boxes, so any other idea is welcome. Many thanks

Comment: Yes I saw this on my breakable boxes, so any other idea is welcome. Many thanks

Comment: An idea ! How to include the command `\vspace*{\baselineskip}\phantom{.}` in the end of the lowerbox ?

Comment: ` after lower`?

Comment: Good idea. The command `after lower*=\vspace*{xx\baselineskip}\phantom{.}` is useful up to a certain value of `xx`, which goes to the end of the current page... But, if we want more space, we can if we want replace it by `after lower*=\vspace*{17\baselineskip}\phantom{.}\newpage \vspace*{yy\baselineskip}\phantom{.}` where `yy` is the number of lines in the page... I think that its a good track...

Comment: A macro where we can choose the number of pages to add, 1 or 2 or 3, may be a good idea